# Javascript clock, change day in advance when clock hits hour

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a countdown of hours/minutes/seconds that is always 6 days in advance.

The trick is, the countdown should reset at 16:00 everyday, not 24:00, and should display the date in 24h format.

The date should be stated below the clock as "Month (September), Day(13)"

This is what I've came-up with:

```
function ShowTimes() {
  var now = new Date();
  now.setDate(now.getDate() + 5)
  if (now.getHours() > 14) {
  var hrs = 39-now.getHours();
} else {
    var hrs = 16-now.getHours();
}
  var mins = 59-now.getMinutes();
  var secs = 59-now.getSeconds();
  var str = '';
      str = now.toString();
      str += '<br>'+hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+secs+' seconds ';
  document.getElementById('countdownToFour').innerHTML = str;

  if (hrs < 0) {
    hrs = 23-now.getHours();
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + 6);
  }
}
var _cntDown;
function StopTimes() {
    clearInterval(_cntDown);
}
```

The problem is I have no idea how to set it to 24h time and how to make it reset at 16.00 instead of 24.00. I seemed to have managed to set it 6 days in advance but I'm not so sure...

Comment: What do you mean by "6 days in advance"? A *clock* can be "in advance", but a *countdown* does only count down to a predetermined datetime. So what do you want?

Comment: I mean I want the date in advance, not the clock as the example below. The clock should be a normal 24:00 countdown that resets to zero and starts again everytime it touches 16:00. Below it, a date should display 6 days in advance. If today is the 11th, then it should read "September 16"

Comment: That's neither a clock nor a countdown when it *counts up* from zero to 16:00. Also, are these "16 h days" somehow related to the actual time or should the counter just start at zero when someone visits the page?

Comment: The idea behind it is to get the current time and display to the user how much time is left until 16.00. At 16.00 sharp everything resets (the countdown now displays that now there are 23:59:59 remaining). The code kinda does that already, but not very well and I'm having issues with displaying the date also, below, unrelated, in the format "11 September". reporter's answer below works well. I'm now only stuck at formatting the date properly in the above mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

Because it was hard to understand your code, so I created a new counter:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var counterIntervalVar;
   var howManyDaysAhead = 0;
   var finishHours = 16;
   var finishMinutes = 0;
   var finishSeconds = 0;
   function ShowTimes()
   {
    var str = "";
    var now = new Date();//Use current time as start time

    //Creating the target time
    var dayIncreasion = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * howManyDaysAhead;
    var targetDateInMilliSeconds = now.getTime();
    var targetDate = new Date(targetDateInMilliSeconds + dayIncreasion); 
    targetDate.setHours(finishHours);
    targetDate.setMinutes(finishMinutes);
    targetDate.setSeconds(finishSeconds);
    targetDateInMilliSeconds = targetDate.getTime();

    //Calculate and show the difference between current time and target time
    var timeDifference = targetDateInMilliSeconds - now.getTime();
    if (timeDifference >= 0)
    {
     var hrs = Math.floor(timeDifference / 1000 / 3600);
     var mins = Math.floor(timeDifference / 1000 / 60) - (hrs * 60);
     sec = Math.floor(timeDifference / 1000) - (hrs * 3600) - (mins * 60);
     str += '<br>'+hrs+' hours '+mins+' minutes '+sec+' seconds ';
     document.getElementById('countdownToFour').innerHTML = str;
    } else {
     howManyDaysAhead++;
    }

    //Give the 'if' query a realistic condition
    if (str == 'x')
    {
     //Stop the loop
     window.clearInterval(counterIntervalVar);
    }
   }

   function initCountdown()
   {
    counterIntervalVar = window.setInterval("ShowTimes()",999);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="initCountdown()">
  <div id="countdownToFour"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this example works for you or at least leads you to the right way.

Comment: This is great! The clock works and correctly resets when it touches 16:00 (or any other given date). However the "days in advance" should be separate (as in display the actual date but 6 days in advance) not included in the countdown. I think I know how to do that though. Not sure about how to make it 7 days in advance if it's a saturday or 8 days in advance if its a sunday.